# JavaScript What is the use of view.js in the form designed through phpform.org

Tags: javascript

I download a form generated by phoform.org. In the page, it includes view.js as follows:

What is the usage of this javascript? Can I remove it without problems?

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('3(7.X){7["R"+a]=a;7["z"+a]=6(){7["R"+a](7.1k)};7.X("1e",7["z"+a])}E{7.19("z",a,15)}2 j=H V();6 a(){2 e=q.1d("1a");3(e){o(e,"P");2 N=B(q,"*","14");3((e.12<=10)||(N=="")){c(e,"P",d)}}4=B(q,"*","1n");k(i=0;i<4.b;i++){3(4[i].F=="1g"||4[i].F=="1f"||4[i].F=="1c"){4[i].1b=6(){r();c(v.5.5,"f",d)};4[i].O=6(){r();c(v.5.5,"f",d)};j.D(j.b,0,4[i])}E{4[i].O=6(){r();c(v.5.5,"f",d)};4[i].18=6(){o(v.5.5,"f")}}}2 C=17.16.13();2 A=q.M("11");3(C.K("J")+1){c(A[0],"J",d)}3(C.K("I")+1){c(A[0],"I",d)}}6 r(){k(2 i=0;i<j.b;i++){o(j[i].5.5,"f")}}6 B(m,y,w){2 x=(y=="*"&&m.Y)?m.Y:m.M(y);2 G=H V();w=w.1m(/\\-/g,"\\\\-");2 L=H 1l("(^|\\\\s)"+w+"(\\\\s|$)");2 n;k(2 i=0;i<x.b;i++){n=x[i];3(L.1j(n.8)){G.1i(n)}}1h(G)}6 o(p,T){3(p.8){2 h=p.8.Z(" ");2 U=T.t();k(2 i=0;i<h.b;i++){3(h[i].t()==U){h.D(i,1);i--}}p.8=h.S(" ")}}6 c(l,u,Q){3(l.8){2 9=l.8.Z(" ");3(Q){2 W=u.t();k(2 i=0;i<9.b;i++){3(9[i].t()==W){9.D(i,1);i--}}}9[9.b]=u;l.8=9.S(" ")}E{l.8=u}}',62,86,'||var|if|elements|parentNode|function|window|className|_16|initialize|length|addClassName|true|_1|highlighted||_10||el_array|for|_13|_6|_c|removeClassName|_e|document|safari_reset||toUpperCase|_14|this|_8|_9|_7|load|_4|getElementsByClassName|_3|splice|else|type|_a|new|firefox|safari|indexOf|_b|getElementsByTagName|_2|onfocus|no_guidelines|_15|event_load|join|_f|_11|Array|_17|attachEvent|all|split|450|body|offsetWidth|toLowerCase|guidelines|false|userAgent|navigator|onblur|addEventListener|main_body|onclick|file|getElementById|onload|radio|checkbox|return|push|test|event|RegExp|replace|element'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "packed" javascript file -- that is to say, the javascript code has been compressed to make the file smaller (and possibly to obfuscate the code to prevent "stealing" ideas).

It presumably adds some kind of functionality to the form, and removing it would remove that functionality.